# Issue importing multiple contributions for same contact

Tags: contributions, import

I am trying to import multiple contributions for a contact.  I am using the following fields for the import:  contact ID, total amount, date received, and financial type.

Civi will only import the first row, and after that it says the contact ID is not valid.  I don't understand, I know I have to use the same contact ID for each row because all contributions are from the same contact.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! It would be helpful if you could edit your question to provide an example of the data you are trying to import.  Perhaps the first five rows of data.  Make sure you remove any personal information first.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it’s an issue with your CSV file/format. Resave the file as CSV and try again.